# missing exec:SQLitePlugin.open in Apache Cordova with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am new in mobile app for the database using sqlite after searching on goolge I configure my project in visual studio but I am getting two error [image]

after click on success get 2nd error

[image]

I am not getting any solution after searching.

I include SQLitePlugin.js in my html page and code for sqlite is

```
(function () {
"use strict";

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'my.db', location: 'default' }, function (db) {

        // Here, you might create or open the table.
        db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE customerAccounts (firstname, lastname, acctNo)');

    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Open database ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });


    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

    // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
    var element = document.getElementById("deviceready");
    element.innerHTML = 'Device Ready';
    element.className += ' ready';
};

function onPause() {
    // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
};

function onResume() {
    // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
};
```

})();

What the mistake here?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase`, SQLite Plugin will execute java native codes, which is not supported by Ripple.
From this [document](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ripple-simulator/):

> Caution: Ripple doesn’t provide a complete simulation of Cordova APIs or native device capabilities (plugins). It also doesn’t simulate specific browser versions for a particular platform. You can achieve this by testing on actual devices or emulators.

Please try that by Android Emulator or real devices.